React Native : Unable to resolve dependency try
I just update expo SDK from 48 to 51 and then face 'unable to resolve dependency error' message whey try to execute command 'npm install'
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: rmstatus@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from react-native-web@0.19.12
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR!     react-native-web@"~0.19.10" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.3.1" from react-dom@18.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"^18.0.0" from react-native-web@0.19.12
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR!     react-native-web@"~0.19.10" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-07-30T04_16_54_388Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-07-30T04_16_54_388Z-debug-0.log

trying to upgrade expo SDK to use latest feature specially expo-camera

You are getting a dependency conflict. use this command, it will hopefully resolve the issue
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

